# Is it pythonic to have lots of constructors in a class?

Tags: python, oop, constructor, ooad

In the [Point class in Geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/point.py), we can see a lot of different ways to call its constructor:

```
>>> p1 = Point(41.5, -81, 0)
>>> p2 = Point(latitude=41.5, longitude=-81)
>>> p3 = Point([41.5, -81, 0])
>>> p4 = Point((41.5, -81))
>>> p5 = Point(p4)
>>> p6 = Point('41.5,-81.0')
>>> p7 = Point('41.5 N -81.0 W')
>>> p8 = Point('-41.5 S, 81.0 E, 2.5km')
>>> p9 = Point('23 26m 22s N 23 27m 30s E 21.0mi')
>>> p10 = Point('''3 26' 22" N 23 27' 30" E''')
```

I wonder if this is good or bad practice, a code smell, if it violates some pythonic idiom or not. Actually the concern would apply for any OO langage, but I am asking about python specifically

Comment: You implement as many constructors as you need. I would not say that 10 is an absurd number. Use inheritance and/or split your classes as it makes sense to reduce the complexity of a single class. On top off all, worrying too much about what other people might or might not consider pythonic is not pythonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It is possible

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # "args" holds a list of positional arguments,
    # "kwargs" holds a dictionary of keyword arguments

    if len(args) == 1 and not kwargs:
        if isinstance(args[0], str):
            if re.match(args[0], some_regex):
                ... # etc
```

---

#### It is code smell

This makes the initialisation code horrible and makes it hard to pass data safely to the constructor, and makes the constructor work unexpectedly with malformed data.

In my opinion, it violates bullets 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 12 and 17 on the Zen of Python (`import this`). So I would say it violates Pythonic idioms.

<sub>• Beautiful is better than ugly.
• Explicit is better than implicit.
• Simple is better than complex.
• Flat is better than nested.
• Readability counts.
• Errors should never pass silently.
• In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
• If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.</sub>

Looking through the linked code, I see

```
POINT_PATTERN = re.compile(r"""
    .*?
    (?P<latitude>
      (?P<latitude_direction_front>[NS])?[ ]*
        (?P<latitude_degrees>-?%(FLOAT)s)(?:[%(DEGREE)sD\*\u00B0\s][ ]*
        (?:(?P<latitude_arcminutes>%(FLOAT)s)[%(PRIME)s'm][ ]*)?
        (?:(?P<latitude_arcseconds>%(FLOAT)s)[%(DOUBLE_PRIME)s"s][ ]*)?
        )?(?P<latitude_direction_back>[NS])?)
    %(SEP)s
    (?P<longitude>
      (?P<longitude_direction_front>[EW])?[ ]*
      (?P<longitude_degrees>-?%(FLOAT)s)(?:[%(DEGREE)sD\*\u00B0\s][ ]*
      (?:(?P<longitude_arcminutes>%(FLOAT)s)[%(PRIME)s'm][ ]*)?
      (?:(?P<longitude_arcseconds>%(FLOAT)s)[%(DOUBLE_PRIME)s"s][ ]*)?
      )?(?P<longitude_direction_back>[EW])?)(?:
    %(SEP)s
      (?P<altitude>
        (?P<altitude_distance>-?%(FLOAT)s)[ ]*
        (?P<altitude_units>km|m|mi|ft|nm|nmi)))?
    .*?$
""" % {
    "FLOAT": r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?',
    "DEGREE": format.DEGREE,
    "PRIME": format.PRIME,
    "DOUBLE_PRIME": format.DOUBLE_PRIME,
    "SEP": r'\s*[,;/\s]\s*',
}, re.X)
```

Personally I'm impressed. It's not easy to make Regex of that size so readable. But it's hardly easy to explain or *simple*.

---

#### There are good alternatives

You can use `staticmethod` or `classmethod` constructors.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0):
        self.a = a # measured in meters
        self.b = b # measured in meters

    @classmethod
    def as_square(cls, a):
        return cls(a, a)

    @classmethod
    def from_inches(cls, a_inches, b_inches):
        inch = 0.0254 # in meters
        return cls(a_inches * inch, b_inches * inch)

    def __repr__(self):
        templ = "<Rectangle: {self.a:.3f} x {self.b:.3f}>"
        return templ.format(self=self)
```

This allows you to instantiate from data while still keeping separate the different methods of doing so.

```
>>> Rectangle(10, 20)
<Rectangle: 10.000 x 20.000>
>>> Rectangle.as_square(100)
<Rectangle: 100.000 x 100.000>
>>> Rectangle.from_inches(2, 4)
<Rectangle: 0.051 x 0.102>
```

---

### On the other hand

Have you seen what `int` can parse?

```
from decimal import Decimal
```

```
int(2546)
#>>> 134
```

```
int(17657.342)
#>>> 17657
```

```
int(Decimal("134"))
#>>> 2546
```

```
int("5443")
#>>> 5443
```

```
int("543", 34)
#>>> 5919
```

```
int("໖᭗")
#>>> 67
```

Say what I like, I'm not going to convince many people that there isn't a precedent for this.

Comment: Very good, nice. Btw, should not the line `def __init__(latitude=0, longitude=0):` have `self` included and read `def __init__(self, latitude=0, longitude=0):` ?

Comment: The static method part of your answer is the part I found most powerful. I am used to see this a lot in Numpy and also in .NET

Comment: @Veedrac But is the `__init__` really static one? I would expect `@staticmethod` decorator around. Could you make working piece of code without all the `...`? So far I see you have some promising idea in mind, which I do not get so far.

Comment: @Veedrac No worry, I have learned something from you today. Edited your sample to make it runnable, I hope, I got it correctly.